# Silverlight System.Security.VerifictionException after Branching in VS

Tags: .net, silverlight, visual-studio-2012, infragistics, verificationexception

I get a `VerificationException` after branching a solution. My folderstructure is ordered like this:

```
 - Dev
 - -- Main
 - Releases
 - -- v1.x.x
 - -- ...
```

If I build & start the solution in the Dev/Main branch everything works just fine. After branching the solution in Release/v.1.x.x and starting from here i get:

```
System.Security.VerificatonException: Operation could destabilize the runtime.
```

I have read all kinds of posts dealing with this Exception but nothing helped.

Some background information:
.NET 4.0, VisualStudio2012, Silverlight 5, Infragistics Library

Comment: Is there a call stack with the exception?

Comment: @alhalama This is the call stack:  System.Security.VerificationException: Operation could destabilize the runtime. 
   bei [AssemblyName].[UserControl].[OnButtonClicked](Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   bei System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
   bei System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton.OnClick()
   bei System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   bei System.Windows.Controls.Control.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(Control ctrl, EventArgs e)
   bei MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(...)

Comment: does this error come when you click the button and if so, what is being done in the button click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Nevertheless thank you for your research.

In the main application there are two Silverlight applications which refers to the assembly System.Windows.Interactivity in two different paths with two different versions. :(